# how can a process execute network code

Tags: c, networking, operating-system

I am a beginner to networking and I have a few questions regarding networking.
1)How can a process execute code that is sent from a different computer on the network. Generally a process's code segment cannot be changed once its loaded to ensure protection. (Also I can execute some arbitrary code to corrupt the process's memory) 
2)Also can a process hear to multiple ports ? And multiple processes can hear to a same port ? For example two https associated with port 80. How to distinguish between the processes and how to ensure protection ?
3)Also I would like to know how listen is implemented in sockets. Are they implemented as software interrupts ?

Any good book recommendations are very much appreciated.

Thanks & Regards,

Mousey.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Q: How can a process execute code sent from another machine?
A: Generally, this is a bad idea as the security concerns are difficult to fully explore.  However, this can be done by saving the network-delivered code to a separate executable and then launching this new program.  This can also be done on *most* systems by just treating the raw bytes received as code; load the bytes into the heap (not the stack!), cast the address to a function pointer, and call it.  Again though, this is almost certainly a **bad idea**.

Q: Can a process listen on multiple ports simultaneously?
A: Yes.  By the way, HTTPS is port 443.  HTTP is port 80.

Q: Can multiple processes listen on the same port (with the same protocol, on the same address)?
A: No.  Other processes might be able to eavesdrop and also receive the packets, but they're not directly bound to the port.  In general, only one process can be bound to a given protocol/port/address 3-tuple.

Q: How is blocking while listening on a socket implemented?
A: By the operating system, in its own fashion.  Generally a thread is moved into the "blocking" state when it calls `accept`, `read`, or `poll`/`select` on a non-ready socket, and will not receive CPU time until some data have arrived.

Comment: If so how can my google chrome firefox able to get http requests at the same time.

Comment: @mousey They are not web servers, so they don't listen on port 80. The other end does.

Comment: To clarify what calmh said above, Chrome and Firefox are listening on (different) random high-numbered ports, not on port 80.

Answer (score 1):

> 1)How can a process execute code that is sent from a different computer on the network. Generally a process's code segment cannot be changed once its loaded to ensure protection.

This has nothing to do with networking. Once you receive the data through a socket, it's in your local memory. What you do after that is OS-specific. For example, on Windows, you can use [`VirtualProtect`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa366898%28v=VS.85%29.aspx) to mark pages as executable.

> 2)Also can a process hear to multiple ports ?

Sure, just create a different socket for each port you want to listen to. Of course, to use them simultaneously, you either need to use non-blocking sockets or run each socket in a separate thread.

> 3)Also I would like to know how listen is implemented in sockets. Are they implemented as software interrupts ?

This is entirely OS-specific. `listen` just sets up the socket so that it can accept connections. Any connection requests that arrive after this (this probably happens somewhere in the TCP/IP driver) are put in a queue by the OS. When you later call `accept`, the OS pulls out the first pending connection from this queue and returns a socket to that.

Comment: Actually, I don't think `listen` is a blocking call at all.  You may be thinking of `accept`.

Comment: yes listen is not a blocking call. Accept or recv are all blocking

Comment: Oops, fixed. I don't know what I was thinking when I wrote that. :)